# Distribution of $r$ objects into $4$ boxes.

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

The number of ways of distributing $r$ distinct objects into $4$ distinct boxes such that box $1$ and $2$ must each hold an even number of objects and box 3 must hold an odd number of objects.

Each object has 4 different options/ boxes to go in, so the total number of ways are $4^r$.
I am not able to further make progress with the conditions to the problem.

The solution links this problem to the exponential function but I'm not able to understand it.

Comment: The rules are not clear...do you mean that the two boxes $\#1,\#2$ must each hold an even number or that between those two boxes there must be an even number (so both could be odd or both even)?

Comment: Regardless of that, I suggest working recursively.  Divide the possible configurations by parities and look at the possible consequences of adding a new object.

Comment: Boxes #1, #2 must each hold an even number of objects.

Comment: So, then you need to divide the $4^r$ total arrangements into $8$ types, according to the possible parities of the first three boxes.  This should at least let you compute the answer for many values of $r$, though it might be hard to get at a sensible closed form this way (that might not exist, in any case).

Comment: Here's a formulation without objects and boxes: How many strings of length $r$ on the digits 1-4 contain an even number of 1s, an even number of 2s, and an odd number of 3s?

Comment: The closed form expression exist for this for all $r.

Comment: Good!  It's still good to do it recursively.  That gives you many cases against which you can test your formula, and getting the first dozen values might well point you toward the closed form.

Comment: Unfortunately, looking at the first few dozen cases myself (as generated brute force by Mathematica) it doesn't seem likely that the closed-form can be readily guessed. (This doesn't mean it doesn't exist, but that trial-and-error is likely not the approach here.)

Comment: One suggestion: If $r$ is even, then box 4 must hold an odd number of objects (and thus at least one). If $r$ is odd, then box 4 must hold an even number of objects. So it may be helpful to consider these cases separately.

Comment: @Semiclassical  Of course, for  modest $r$, or larger, the answer must be $\frac {4^r}8$, or very close to it. (all the possible parities must be more or less equal at some point). Taking the difference gives you an easily identified sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that generating functions are good at.

The generating function for the number of ways to distribute the $r$ objects over the $4$ boxes without constraints, with $a$ through $d$ marking the number of objects in each box, is $(a+b+c+d)^r$, and we get the total number of arrangements, summed over all possible distributions over the boxes, by substituting $a=b=c=d=1$, which yields $4^r$.

If we had a single constraint that the first box must contain an even number of objects, the generating function would be $\frac12\left((a+b+c+d)^r+(-a+b+c+d)^r\right)$ (which includes only the even powers of $a$), so the number of arrangements, obtained by substituting $a=b=c=d=1$, would be $\frac12\left(4^r+2^r\right)$.

Likewise, if we had a single constraint that the third box must contain an odd number of objects, the generating function would be $\frac12\left((a+b+c+d)^r-(a+b-c+d)^r\right)$ (which includes only the odd powers of $c$), so the number of arrangements, obtained by substituting $a=b=c=d=1$, would be $\frac12\left(4^r-2^r\right)$.

As it is, we have three simultaneous constraints, and we have to apply them one after the other to get the corresponding generating function that contains only the even powers of $a$ and $b$ and the odd powers of $c$:

\begin{eqnarray}
f_0(a,b,c,d)
&=&(a+b+c+d)^r\;,\\
f_1(a,b,c,d)
&=&
\frac12(f_0(a,b,c,d)+f_0(-a+b+c+d))
\\
&=&
\frac12\left((a+b+c+d)^r+(-a+b+c+d)^r\right)\;,
\\
f_2(a,b,c,d)
&=&\frac12(f_1(a,b,c,d)+f_1(a,-b,c,d))
\\
&=&\frac14\left((a+b+c+d)^r+(-a+b+c+d)^r+(a-b+c+d)^r+(-a-b+c+d)^r\right)\;,
\\
f_3(a,b,c,d)
&=&\frac12(f_2(a,b,c,d)-f_2(a,b,-c,d))
\\
&=&\frac18\left((a+b+c+d)^r+(-a+b+c+d)^r+(a-b+c+d)^r+(-a-b+c+d)^r\right.\\
&&\left.-\left((a+b-c+d)^r+(-a+b-c+d)^r+(a-b-c+d)^r+(-a-b-c+d)^r\right)\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Again, the total number is obtained by substituting $a=b=c=d=1$, which yields

$$
\frac18\left(4^r+2^r-(-2)^r\right)\;.
$$

The first few values for $r=1,2,3$ are $1,2,10$, which you can check by hand.

(Note that the result doesn’t hold for $r=0$, since in this case e.g. $(a+b-c-d)^r$ can’t be treated as $0$; we actually get a $1$ from each of the eight terms, and they cancel, yielding the correct count of $0$.)

*Edit*:

This is a too-long-for-a-comment response to @Semiclassical’s observation that the result is exactly $\frac18$ of the unconstrained result if $r$ is even.

If $r$ is even, the fourth box must also contain an odd number of objects, so the count is the same as if we had two even and two odd constraints.

On the level of the generating functions, no $2^r$ term results in this case because the terms obtained by exchanging the even and odd constraints have opposite signs and cancel.

But there’s also a direct combinatorial argument. If we distribute an even number of balls, there are $8$ possible resulting parity patterns for the boxes – all even, all odd, or $\binom42=6$ arrangements of two even, two odd. If we distribute $r-1$ objects without constraints, there’s exactly one box in which we can put the $r$-th object in order to make all boxes have the same parity. Thus, of the $8$ possible parity patterns, all even and all odd together have $\frac14=\frac28$ of the sequences, exactly their fair share. Since there’s permutation symmetry among the remaining $6$ parity patterns, they must each also have their fair share, $\frac184^r$.

Comment: An interesting feature of this is that, for even $r$, the number of ways is decreased by a factor of exactly 8. There is presumably a good explanation for this but I don't see it off the top of my head.

Comment: @Semiclassical: Interesting – I edited the answer to provide explanations for that.

Comment: I put an alternative approach for even $r$, if you know a similar approach for odd $r$, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments in the other answer, I split the case into two possibilities; even or odd $r$

**Even $r$**

*At least one of box 1 and 2 non-empty*:

1. Split $r$ objects into two non-empty groups with even number of objects.
2. Say first group has $m$ objects. Split this group into two sub-groups with even number of objects. Put the first sub-group into box 1 and the other into box 2.
3. Split the second group into two sub-groups with odd number of objects. Put the first sub-group into box 3 and the other into box 4.

Respectively from step 1 to 3, there are $\frac{1}{2}2^{r}-2$, $\frac{1}{2}2^{m}$, and $\frac{1}{2}2^{r-m}$ ways. Combined, there are $\frac{1}{8}4^{r}-\frac{1}{2}2^{r}$ possible distribution.

*Box 1 and 2 empty*:

Split the objects into two groups with odd number of objects. Put one group into box 3 and the other to box 4. There are $\frac{1}{2}2^{r}$ ways to do this.

*Total*: $\frac{1}{8}4^{r}$

**Odd $r$**

*At least one of box 1 and 2 non-empty*:

1. Split $r$ objects into two non-empty groups with even and odd number of objects.
2. Say the even group has $m$ objects. Split this group into two sub-groups with even number of objects. Put the first sub-group into box 1 and the other into box 2.
3. Split the odd group into two sub-groups with odd and even number of objects. Put the odd sub-group into box 3 and the even sub-group into box 4.

Respectively from step 1 to 3, there are $\frac{1}{2}2^{r}-1$, $\frac{1}{2}2^{m}$, and $\frac{1}{2}2^{r-m}$ ways. Combined, there are $\frac{1}{8}4^{r}-\frac{1}{2}2^{r}$ possible distribution.

*Box 1 and 2 empty*:

Split the objects into two groups with odd and even number of objects. Put odd group into box 3 and the even group to box 4. There are $\frac{1}{2}2^{r}$ ways to do this.

*Total*: $\frac{1}{8}4^{r}+\frac{1}{4}2^{r}$